# Unable to create AVD -- System images installed, restarted eclipse and verified SDK path -- still no luck

Tags: android, eclipse

I cannot create an AVD in eclipse for use in Android Development. After I fill out all the fields and hit OK, it doesn't do anything. I am running Mac OS X 10.9.2.

I tried all the suggestions on stackoverflow I could find. I am looking for any other suggestions to get this working.

- Installed System Images

[image: Platforms]

- Restarted Eclipse
- Verified SDK path

[image: SDK]

- Created AVD using system image

[image: AVD]

- Installation Details

[image: Installation Details]

Revert Error:

[image: Revert Error]

Comment: If you are using version 22.6 tools and plugin, then this is a known bug:https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66661

Comment: I posted installation details. I am running 22.6 of Android DDMS. Is that what you were referring to? Are there any workarounds?

Comment: Tried reverting install but it didn't work (Errors shown in above question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This workaround is from Raghunandan.

In Eclipse, open the SDK Manager (via toolbar or Window menu) > Tools > Manager AVDs.

This will invoke the external version of the AVD Manager which will properly generate AVDs. Other workaround: use the command-line version (Shell or cmd.exe, cd SDK, "tools\android.bat avd").

Comment: Thanks, for people on the mac, what I ended up doing was: `cd adt-bundle-mac-x86_64/sdk/tools/` then run `android avd`